# Is there any application for manual logging with timestamps?

Tags: files, log

I would like to find an application or an extension for an editor that allows me to record phases of a process by entering status messages. Ideally, the output would be a logfile with timestamps for each message that I've entered.

Nowadays I have to test fairly complicated websites and I would like to be able to exactly know what I do in each step, so I would like to submit a status message on each step I do, much like a commit message in version control systems.

Do you know anything similar?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems a very bad idea to log EVERY line entered in an editor, but knowing the source problem can help to suggest a solution.

Comment: @enzotib sorry, I've tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Would having an editor bind a command to insert the date do?

Comment: That would be one way, but finding a dedicated solution would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [gtimelog](http://mg.pov.lt/gtimelog/) does what you're after:

[image]

It is available in Ubuntu as the `gtimelog` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gtimelog
```

Comment: Yeah, this is excellent. I wanted this exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Gedit as a *Insert Date/Time* plugin. You can configure it for a given format and to not ask confirmation. You should call it explicitly from *Edit* menu, though.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's okay for inserting the date, but I would like to have a dedicated solution for this - the more comfortable the better. I will spend quite a bit of time with this tool...

Answer (score 2):

gtimelog looks very nice, this is would I would have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) "$@" >> "$USER/logfile"
```

if you save this in `/usr/bin/log` or in `~/bin/log` you can just type in

```
log some message
```

and will end up with

```
Fr 12. Aug 11:30:50 CEST 2011 some message
```

in the file.

Comment: Yes of course. I've started this question to save myself from playing around with Python, because I wouldn't stop myself from adding features and such :D

Comment: Sure, one gets carried away pretty quickly …